# Error 403 when refreshing an angular app in Wildfly

Tags: angular, wildfly, war, http-status-code-403

I have implemented an angular 6 app using hash location strategy and want to deploy it as WAR in Wildfly. The application runs fine, however reloading the page (e.g. http://localhost:9390/MyApp/app/#/login) results in an 403 forbidden error. Here is the setup:

## WAR file:

```
/app/* -> angular app generated by ng-cli
/error403.html -> simple error page
/WEB-INF
/WEB-INF/web.xml
/WEB-INF/classes/... REST services
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>app/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error403.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

To whom it may concern: 
The 403 error occurs because of the hash based location strategy. Everything beginning with the # in the URI is removed before it is sent to the client. In my example the URL ends with `/app/` which is recognized as directory by undertow. As directory listing is not allowed by default, a 403 is returned. The solution for is to implement a WebFilter which detects this request and redirects to the angular page `/app/index.html`.

Comment: can you post your web filter implementation .